# WPF - Grid lines in datagrid (also passing through header)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, gridlines

I need to show gridlines in a data grid, also a passing-through grid.

I am not able to do so as, by default, gridlines only pass through data (not all the way to the bottom of the grid).

One way I can think of is to have a styling datagrid header and place the border inside datatemplate. But manually doing it, there may be an issue of alignment of gridlines and the border.

How do I elegantly achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Vertical gridlines in a ListView*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045966/vertical-gridlines-in-a-listview/10047450#10047450).

I tested the approach in that post, and it will solve the issue of gridlines, by drawing them beyond data. However, in applying a new template to

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

you ***will*** loose the headers.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer